# Vue - call methods in mustache

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

```html
<span>{{ count }}</span>      <- output: 104     why not 3
<span>{{ move() }}</span>     <- output: 104     why not 4

<script>
data() {
    return {
        count: 3
    }
},
methods: {
    move() {
        return this.count++;
    }
}
</script>
```

> [Vue warn]: Maximum recursive updates exceeded in component . This means you have a reactive effect that is mutating its own dependencies and thus recursively triggering itself. Possible sources include component template, render function, updated hook or watcher source function.

Why...not 3 or 4?

Answer (score 1):

it's because you have `move()` in the template, and every time the template renders, the value gets updated, causing the template to render again.

This is a recursion, which the browser notified you exceeded maximum count, stopping at 104.

You can assign the function to execute on click like so:

```html
<span>{{ count }}</span>
<span @click="move">move</span>
<script>
data() {
    return {
        count: 3
    }
},
methods: {
    move() {
        return this.count++;
    }
}
<script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a recursive rendering when you are modifying `count`, If you want to print you can add one and avoid modify `count`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      count: 3
    }
  },
  methods: {
    move() {
      return this.count + 1;
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <span>{{ count }}</span>
  <span>{{ move() }}</span>
</div>
```